# XNA 4 GraphicsDevice

Tags: graphics, xna-4.0, dispose

From my few years of experience programming in graphics, one thing that I have learned is that you should never pass in a reference to a graphics context to an object and operate on it for the duration of the program (JOGL explicitly states this). A context can be invalidated when something such as the graphics device (GPU) is reset, turned off, or some other weird thing happens.
  I have recently delved back into programming in XNA 4.0, and one of my projects involves objects needing to know about the size of the window/viewport, when the window is resized, and when dynamic buffers have lost their content (requiring the buffers to be rebuilt on a possibly invalidated GraphicsDevice). Instead of passing in the GraphicsDevice and GameWindow to numerous methods in the update phase or for Disposal, I have opted to pass them into constructors. For example:

```
public Camera(GameWindow w, GraphicsDeviceManager m) {
    // ... Yada-yada matrices
    gdm = m;
    window = w;
    window.ClientSizeChanged += OnWindowResize;
}
public void Dispose() {
    window.ClientSizeChanged -= OnWindowResize;
    window = null;
    gdm = null;
}
// Control Logic ...
public void OnWindowResize(object Sender, EventArgs args) {
    Vector2 s = new Vector2(gdm.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.TitleSafeArea.Width, gdm.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.TitleSafeArea.Height);
    // Recalculate Projection ...
}
```

Is it safe to do something like this, or is something happening in the background that I need to be aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem in my current game project by running the game as a singleton, which makes it available in a static context within the namespace.  `Game.Instance.graphicsDevice` will always point to the current graphics device object, even if the context has changed.  XNA raises various events when the context is invalidated/changed/reset/etc., and you can reload/re-render things and resize buffers as needed by hooking in to these events.

Alternatively, you could pass `GraphicsDevice` with the `ref` keyword, which might be a quick, drop-in fix by simply being the same reference as the original caller, assuming that caller that instantiated your objects either has the original reference object or had the `GraphicsDevice` passed to it with `ref` as well.